# Что - какая здесь часть речи?

Tags: части-речи

Что она, глухая или глухонемая, эта девочка?

Здесь_что_ какой частью речи является?

Comment: Я бы в этом предложении иначе расставил знаки препинания

Answer (score 1):

Вопросительная частица. Она употреблена в начале вопросительного предложения для выражения сомнения, удивления, предположения.

Comment: Извините, конечно, но у меня вопрос: почему Вы не принимаете ответы на Ваши вопросы? Вы с ними не согласны или не хотите оценить работу тех, кто отвечает? Получается, что Вы просто используете сайт для решения домашних заданий, это некорректно для данного сайта.

Comment: Спасибо большое, Людмила, за ваши профессиональные ответы. К сожалению, я не знаю, на какую кнопку надо нажать, чтобы принять ответ.

Comment: Вверху слева около всех ответов  на Вашей страничке(под кулачками с цифрами) есть кружок с галочкой, жмите на него возле того ответа, который считаете лучшим.

Answer (score 1):

Да, это частица, т.к. в отличие от местоимения не является членом предложения и в отличие от союза не связывает части сложного предложения.

Answer (score 0):

Я тоже вначале подумал, что "что" - это частица, но смутили знаки препинания в приведенном предложении, поэтому мне кажется, что "что" является здесь вопросительным местоимением. На эту мысль наталкивает возможность заменить слово "что" местоимением "какая?" или словами "чем является?"

Comment: Нет, это вопросительная частица, посмотрите здесь:http://rusgram.narod.ru/1689-1705.html. Вопросительные частицы часто выступают в свободном соединении друг с другом: Что, устал, а?; Что, не подождать ли нам?; Заснул, что ли,а?; Ну как, согласен, а? А пунктуация здесь разговорная,всё нормально.

Comment: Уважаемая Людмила! А разве, согласно Вашему пояснению, пунктуация не должна быть иной? (Что, она глухая или глухонемая, эта девочка?)А как Вы смотрите на такую пунктуацию: Что она - глухая или глухонемая, эта девочка?

Comment: Это уж как автор посмотрит, как произнесёт,всё будет правильно, перед однородными членами возможно и тире. Но это будет уже Ваша фраза, а не авторская.